# Querying tree tables linked to one table

Tags: jquery, sql, sql-server

I have tree tables that I use as index:

link_flavor_and_iceCream having as columns: flavor_ID, iceCream_ID 
link_color_and_iceCream having as columns: color_ID, iceCream_ID 
link_fans_and_iceCream having as columns: fan_ID, iceCream_ID 
Each iceCream can have many diferent flavors, colors and fans

I need to query all icecreams that has flavor "vanila" or "chocolate", and color "pink" or "red" or "brown", and "jack" or "joe" as fans...

How do I do that? How can I put all that on the same view???

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Series of inner joins using or statements on the join criteria or in statements...  Yes you can put it all in one view.

Comment: Are you just asking how to build a SQL Statement?

Comment: This reeks of homework question. My suggestion would be to try to figure it out and let us know where you get stuck. Good luck homie.

Answer (score 0):

Given we don't know field names for your limiting critiera or what iceCream table (or even if you have one) what it looks like...

something like this...

```
SELECT IC.Name
FROM iceCream IC
INNER JOIN Link_flavor_and_IceCream ICF
 IC.IceCream_ID = ICF.IceCream_ID
 and favor in ('Vanila', 'Chocolate')
INNER JOIN Link_color_AndIceCream ICC
 and ICC.IceCream_Id = IC.IceCream_ID
 and color in ('Pink','Red','Brown')
INNER JOIN Link_Fans_and_IceCream ICFan
 and IC.IceCream_ID = ICFan.IceCream_ID
 and ICFan.Name  in ('Jack','Joe')
```

Or...

```
SELECT IC.Name
FROM iceCream IC
INNER JOIN Link_flavor_and_IceCream ICF
 IC.IceCream_ID = ICF.IceCream_ID
INNER JOIN Link_color_AndIceCream ICC
 and ICC.IceCream_Id = IC.IceCream_ID
INNER JOIN Link_Fans_and_IceCream ICFan
 and IC.IceCream_ID = ICFan.IceCream_ID
WHERE
     IFC.favor in ('Vanila', 'Chocolate')
 and ICC.color in ('Pink','Red','Brown')
 and ICFan.Name  in ('Jack','Joe')
```

Or a multitude of other ways... including use of or statements instead of in

Comment: Thank you for your answer XQbert,
the "where" clause is not needed?

Comment: In the first one no.  In the second one yes.  The reason it's not needed in the first one is because the limiting criteria was placed on the joins between the tables.  Thus a where isn't needed.  when using outer joins this becomes especially important.  on INNER Joins these two queries will result in the same result.  The 2nd is more common to see while the first involves greater flexibility if you switch to needing outer joins.